# Can't get latexindent to work: "Could not open defaultSettings.yaml"

Tags: miktex, latexindent

So. I would like to use `latexindent`. I use the 2.9 version of MiKTeX and I installed `latexindent` via the MiKTeX console.

Every time I try to use `latexindent` (even from console) I get:

> Could not open defaultSettings.yaml at C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/scripts/latexindent/LatexIndent/GetYamlSettings.pm line 69.

The defaultSettings.yaml file is indeed at `C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\scripts\latexindent` and this is exactly where the line 69 is checking:

```perl
die "Could not open defaultSettings.yaml" if(!$defaultSettings);
```

as stated in:

```perl
$defaultSettings = YAML::Tiny->read( "$FindBin::RealBin/../../texmf-dist/scripts/latexindent/defaultSettings.yaml");
```

I don't know Perl, so the error might be somewhere else. I have no idea how to proceed, I wasted some good hours on that already :/

Comment: Hello! Are you using latexindent.exe ?

Comment: Yes, that is in the same folder as the defaultSettings.yaml, latexindex.pl and the LatexIndent folder insinde the miktex\scripts folder. @cmhughes

Comment: Could you try copying default settings.yaml from https://github.com/cmhughes/latexindent.pl into the directory with latexindent.exe?

Comment: I just downloaded the complete zip from the repository and put it in the script folder of miktex. Same error. @cmhughes

Comment: How about if you get latexindent.exe and default settings.yaml from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latexindent. These are you he only two files you should require for Windows